# Is it possible to set the monitor Screen resolution using web driver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to set the monitor Screen resolution using web driver?

I need to set the screen resolution(not the browser width and height) before running selenium tests. Please someone help me in this.

Comment: If it is not possible with Selenium, please tell me how to set the screen resolution with the help of Java.?

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible via WebDriver. Selenium can only operate a browser, nothing more.

[However, simple Java code can achieve what you want. Google furiously.](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20set%20screen%20resolution)

Comment: Thank you Slanec. I googled the same. I just wanted to know, whether selenium does that. Thanks anyway.!!